# How do I let php know that I made changes In input?

Tags: php

Well I have this html:

```html
<?php
        if(isset($_POST['do_change'])) {
        // that is the place where i need to place if(changes have been made in input)
        echo "yeey y made changes";
     }
        ?>
```

and changes php:

```html
       <form action="changes.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="goose">
        <input type="text" name="cat">
        <input type="submit" name="do_change">
        </form>
```

I need if `<input name="goose" value="hey">` and `<input name="cat" value="">` display text :"you have wrote something in input with name goose and nothing with name cat"

Comment: Are you simply asking for `if($_POST['goose'] !== '')` …?

Comment: not exactly. for example: I ve made changes in 1 input, but other is has not changed. and I need if input with name  GOOSE has changed it will echo GOOSE but if other input has not changed I need to display NOT GOOSE

Comment: I can’t make sense of what you are saying there. Please edit your question, and explain _exactly_ what you need in the four possible cases (if we are talking about two input fields now, which your “example code” did not even match to begin with.)

Comment: ok give me a minute dude

Comment: done. sry for my English btw.

Comment: So you want to check that the first one is _not_ an empty string then, and that the second one is.

Comment: yes. and I prefer more than two if it s possible

Comment: First of all, why are you not saying that to begin with, why do we have to extract every. single. piece. of _relevant_ information from you one after the other? And secondly, this is again quite vague now. What _exactly_ do you want now, if you had three fields? Should the first one be filled, and the other _two_ should be empty? Or the other way around? Or _any_ one of them filled, the other two empty? There are really quite a different number of possiblities here, so _you_ need to come up with a _precise_ requirement first of all.

Comment: I just can't explain cuz of my English. Don't be that rude. Im from russia. Wanna try to be Russian trying to express himself on stack overflow? And I want to:
If 1 field filled-do nothing. If both-echo something. If three-echo sth.

Comment: Then you best loop over your input parameters, and _count_ which ones are filled, and which ones are empty. After the loop, you then check if that counter is > 1, or not.

Comment: ok thx. can u make this like an answer to I mark y?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if the user filled out more than one of your text input fields, you can for example do something like this:

```
// array with names of the fields you want to check
$fieldnames = ['goose', 'cat', 'kangaroo'];

// initialize counter of filled fields with 0
$filled = 0;

// loop over the field names
foreach($fieldnames as $fieldname) {
  // check if a value under that name exists in the $_POST array,
  // and if so, that its value is not the empty string
  if(isset($_POST[$fieldname]) && $_POST[$fieldname] !== '') {
    $filled++;
  }
}

if($filled > 1) {
  echo 'You filled more than one field.';
}
```

Comment: If you don’t want to have to specify the possible field names upfront - then you can also loop over the contents of $_POST instead, then you will only have to ignore the entry that was caused by the submit button. (Assuming your form contains _only_ such text fields you want to apply this check on, besides the submit button.)

Answer (score -1):

You forgot  `{}`

First page:

```
<form action="changes.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="goose">
<input type="submit" name="do_change">
</form>
```

changes.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['do_change'])){
// that is the place where i need to place if(changes have been made in input)
echo "yeey y made changes";
}
```